# Read ip camera stream video on python using opencv3

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

I installed opencv3 [installation link](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-raspberry-pi/) on my raspberrypi 3 and i've tested this, everything is ok, but when i try to read the ipcamera video stream encountered this error

```
self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://*:*@{}:525/stream2".format(ip_camera_address))
```

```bsh
    'NoneType' object has no attribute '__array_interface__'
```

Reading the webcam with the usb interface and everything is ok

I think my problem is in ffmpeg library, I try to install this library but it won't fix.

Comment: I take it `*:*@{}` is a place-holder for a valid `user:pass@host`

Comment: This is just an example. I used the user and password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I install opencv again [[best link for install this](https://www.alatortsev.com/2018/09/05/installing-opencv-3-4-3-on-raspberry-pi-3-b/)]  and i try to install FFmpeg from [repository](http://git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg%20--depth=1). affter installation of ffmepg i tried to read ipcamera video stream with this script

> Note : after finshing opencv cmake, FFmpeg subitems most all get YES.

[image]

```py
self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://user:password@{}:525/stream2".format(ip_camera_address))
```

And It worked successfully.

This tutorial help me to install ffmpeg on raspberry pi [link](http://jollejolles.com/installing-ffmpeg-with-h264-support-on-raspberry-pi/)

Answer (score 1):

if you need run USBcam

```
import cv2 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

if you need run IPcam

```
import cv2 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.64/1')

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: It is a true method for read video stream at IP camera, But my problem is fix ffmpeg in openCV ,My sintex is true because I have tested this on my PC, But this does not work properly on raspberry

Comment: This is often and I had something working on the PC but it does not work on raspberries, try gstreamer

Answer (score 0):

First check your camera providers correct address format:

I used Dahua IPC-HFW2231S camera

Take a look to correct structure
https://www.camera-sdk.com/p_6658-how-to-connect-to-your-dahua-ip-camera-onvif.html

Examples to my camera
https://dahuawiki.com/Remote_Access/RTSP_via_VLC

And the working code below. subtype (Sub stream) can be changed between main stream and sub stream.

`cap=cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://admin:PASSWORD@192.168.100.108:554//cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1')`

Comment: Please take a moment to review [Markdown formatting](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/editing-help).